# Запрос нескольких разрешений для одной операции (Android)

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-permissions

Для выполнения одной из операций требуется 3 разрешения:

- Доступ к камере;
- Сохранение файлов;
- Чтение файлов.

Если запросить разрешения так, то для их получения нужно нажимать на кнопку операции 2 раза.

```
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[] manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_ID_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Если объединить условные операторы через `||` приложение запрашивает только разрешение на доступ к камере и всё. Дальше сколько ни нажимай кнопку всё без толку. Ни запроса разрешений, ни самого действия.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно запрашивать разрешения в подобных ситуациях?

Версия Android 6 (API 23).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте отдельный метод, который будет запрашивать все разрешения разом

```
private void requestPerms(){
        String[] perm = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,perm,123);
        }
    }
```

Соответственно после каждой проверки вызывайте этот метод.

```
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPerms();
}
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPerms();
}
if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPerms();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!